# rpmbuild on CentOS: no such file or directory

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I have created a simple RPM on Fedora27 and it worked fine. It just copied files from tar.gz to /usr/bin/.

When I tried to install this RPM on CentOS I got:

```
# rpm -i RPMS/x86_64/my_rpm-0.0-5.x86_64.rpm --force
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.26)(64bit) is needed by my_rpm-0.0-5.x86_64
```

So I assumed I will need to create the RPM on CentOS.
But when I do so I get a weird: 'No such file or directory' that I don't get on Fedora27. Here is a sketch of my spec file:

```
%define _topdir     %(pwd)
%define name        my_rpm
%define release     5
%define version     0.0
%define buildroot   %{_topdir}/%{name}-%{release}-root

BuildRoot:      %{buildroot}
Summary:        my_rpm
License:        -
Name:           %{name}
Release:        %{release}
Version:        %{version}
Source:         %{name}-%{version}-%{release}.tar.gz
Prefix:         /usr
Group:          Tools

%description
This is my_rpm spec file

%prep
%setup -q -n %(arch)/%{name}-%{version}

%install
install -D my_app -t %{buildroot}/usr/bin/my_rpm/

%files
/usr/bin/my_rpm/*
```

When I try to build the RPM for it I get:

```
# rpmbuild -v -bb --clean SPECS/bpf.spec
+ install -D app -t /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_rpm-0.0-5.x86_64/usr/bin/my_rpm/
install: failed to access '/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_rpm-0.0-5.x86_64/usr/bin/my_rpm/': No such file or directory
```

The same SPEC exactly runs smoothly on Fedora27.
What should I change in it my spec file so that it would work both on Fedora27 and CentOS7? or maybe I can fix my initial problem with Glibc?

### **EDIT 1**

I added the "mkdir -p ..." command under install and the build was successful but it still gives me the same error, that I need Glibc 2.6.
What I don't understand is why during the build it says:

```
Requires: libc.so.6()(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.26)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit) libelf.so.1()(64bit) libelf.so.1(ELFUTILS_1.0)(64bit) rtld(GNU_HASH)
```

### Edit 2(solution)

I got it to work. My executables are compiled C code. So I had to re-compile everything on CentOS and then build the rpm. Now it works on both Fedora and CentOS.

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track; the `glibc` stuff is because CentOS is older. **Don't build RPMs as root!** I don't know for sure (so not making an answer) but I'm going to assume `install` on C7 doesn't auto-create directories? Try adding `mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/bin/my_rpm/` to the `%install` stanza?

Comment: Glad that you make it work. You have lots of issues in your spec though. Mentioning just few: Do not include pre-built binaries if possible - compile them in %install section. Do not define _topdir in spec file. This should be kept as is or override in ~/.rpmmacros file. Do not define buildroot and BuildRoot. There is sane default since RHEL6+.  Do not define %name, just write the name in Name tag and this will automatically create %name macro. The same for Release and Version.

Comment: Additionaly if you want to build CentOS 7 package on Fedora, you can run 'mock -r epel-7-x86_64 your.src.rpm' and it will create CentOS chroot and build the package there.